# SoftwareApplication and WebApplication structured data not shown in search console enhancements

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets, structured-data

I have a pricing page with `SoftwareApplication` structured data that has a sub-type of `WebApplication` set. The structured data rendered properly and saved to indexed page content.

But I see only these enhancements at Search Console:

- Core Web Vitals
- Mobile Usability
- Breadcrumbs
- FAQ

Is there way to include SoftwareApplication/WebApplication into enhancements section of Google Search Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use structured data, it doesn't show up in the "enhancement" section of Google Search Console.   To test your structured data and preview rich results in Google Search Console you need to open the [Structured Data Markup Helper tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/).  The documentation for the tool is [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?hl=en).

Google's [documentation for `SoftwareApp` rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/software-app) also suggests using the [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) which does not appear to be part of Search Console.

Google's [rich result gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) labels `SoftwareApp` as "beta".  It seems like they are testing rich results for software.   Don't be surprised if the rich results don't show up or Google discontinues them.